# How do you use client certificates when authenticating using SALS External mechanism on OpenLDAP Server?

Tags: authentication, authorization, openldap, x509, sasl

I have generated client certificates, how do I use the client certificates to authenticate the user to LDAP server just using LDAP utils ldapsearch,ldapmodify? I want a password less authentication process for the user.

Answer (score 2):

The certificate and key settings are documented in the [ldap.conf(5)](https://openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap.conf&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&arch=default&format=html) man page. You are looking for the `TLS_CERT` and `TLS_KEY` options.

Note that these are documented as **user-only** options, meaning that they can be set as environment variables (respectively `LDAPTLS_CERT` and `LDAPTLS_KEY`) or in a personal `ldaprc` file, but not in the system-wide `ldap.conf` file.

With the certificate and key settings, use `-Y EXTERNAL` with the ldap tools. For example (using the environment variables):

```
LDAPTLS_CERT=user-cert.pem LDAPTLS_KEY=user-priv.key ldapwhoami -H ldap://server -ZZ -Y  EXTERNAL
```